# Latex text appears weird above the figures

Tags: floats, positioning

I tried to add some explanations above my figures. However, they look really weird. Maybe because I use centering, but if I get rid of the centering, my pictures will not place correctly. Please help me. Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
 \caption{Police}
This figure plots the survey respondents' attitudes to contacting police officers for four categories of cybercrime from 2012 to 2014. Panel from (a) to (d) plots police contact relating to online identity theft, and consumer fraud. hated speech, and denial of service, respectively.\break
\\
\\
 \label{Police}
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dentity_Theft_police}
     \caption{Identity Theft}
     \label{fig1:police}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ConsumerFraud_police}
     \caption{Consumer Fraud}
     \label{fig2:police}
 \end{subfigure}
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{RHR_police}
     \caption{Hated Speech}
     \label{fig3:police}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{DOS_police}
     \caption{Denial of Service}
     \label{fig4:police}
 \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any advice will be appreciated!
[image]

Comment: remove `\\ \\ ` replace by  blank line. You should also have a blank line before `\medskip`  or the space is not added where you expected.

Comment: Forgive the loathsome nitpicking, but shouldn't it be "hate speech" without a "d"?

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and comments! Yes, it should be hate speech. I mistype it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap your text into a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!] 
 \caption{Police}
\parbox{\linewidth}{This figure plots the survey respondents' attitudes to contacting police officers for four categories of cybercrime from 2012 to 2014. Panel from (a) to (d) plots police contact relating to online identity theft, and consumer fraud. hated speech, and denial of service, respectively.}
\medskip
 \label{Police}
 \centering%
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
     \caption{Identity Theft}
     \label{fig1:police}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
     \caption{Consumer Fraud}
     \label{fig2:police}
 \end{subfigure}
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
     \caption{Hated Speech}
     \label{fig3:police}
 \end{subfigure}%
 \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
     \caption{Denial of Service}
     \label{fig4:police}
 \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that I also changed the width of your subfigures to `0.5\linewidth` and removed the ugly "formatting" via linebreaks. Furthermore I replaced your images with images which are available for me.
[image: Result]

### Edit

Or simply do what David Carlisle recommends, this works too `;-)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! I will try both

Comment: @Snow You can accept the answer if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The commands

```
\break
\\
\\
\centering
```

are the problems: the `\centering` affects also the paragraph it's issued in and `\\` doesn't end paragraphs. Avoid using `\\` in normal text.

Also look closely at the placement of `\medskip` (between blank lines) and `\hfill`.

Don't use just `[h!]`. It will block the queue if no space is available.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp] 

\caption{Police}\label{Police}

This figure plots the survey respondents' attitudes to contacting 
police officers for four categories of cybercrime from 2012 to 2014. 
Panel from (a) to (d) plots police contact relating to online identity 
theft, and consumer fraud. hated speech, and denial of service, 
respectively.

\bigskip

\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Identity Theft}
  \label{fig1:police}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Consumer Fraud}
  \label{fig2:police}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Hated Speech}
  \label{fig3:police}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.485\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Denial of Service}
  \label{fig4:police}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]